# UWP Custom rectangle shape

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <toolkitControls:DropShadowPanel Style="{StaticResource DefaultCardDropShadowEffect}">
        <Grid CornerRadius="5" Background="{Binding AccentColor}" Padding="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <!-- Rectangle for border aroung the card -->
            <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="3" Fill="{Binding AccentColor}" StrokeLineJoin="Round" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeDashArray="4" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
            <!-- Overflowing rectangle -->
            <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0,-2,0,-2" Fill="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" AllowDrop="True">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform SkewX="-25" TranslateX="-80"/>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>

            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="10" Margin="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- Image and name layout -->
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Visibility="{Binding ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}">
                        <Ellipse Fill="Orange" Width="45" Height="45"/>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Accept" Foreground="White"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Ellipse Visibility="{Binding ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}" Width="45" Height="45">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Samples/SampleImage.png"/>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CardName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="{StaticResource BigTextSize}" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="0" Margin="0" Width="20" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource TiltableAccentButton}">
                        <Button.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Viewbox Width="15" Height="15">
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Edit" Foreground="White"/>
                                </Viewbox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Button.ContentTemplate>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>

                <!-- Number layour -->
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding CardNumber}" Margin="0,10,0,10" FontSize="24"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CardHolderName}" FontSize="{StaticResource BigTextSize}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CardExpireDate}" FontSize="{StaticResource BigTextSize}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </toolkitControls:DropShadowPanel>
</Grid>
```

I want my second rectangle in the XAML code to have the form like the white one on the following screen.

[image]

In the current XAML code I have done it using the Skew and Translate transforms, but the rectangle is Skewed on both sides and moreover is translated left and goes out of the bound of the parent element.

[image]

How can I do so Rectangle will be skewed only on the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *clip* it.

You can attach a `RectangleGeometry` to your root `Grid` in XAML but you will need to manually update the `Rect` inside the `SizeChanged` event whenever its width or height gets updated.

```
<Grid x:Name="Root" SizeChanged="OnRootGridSizeChanged">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, WidthOfRoot, HeightOfRoot" />
    </Grid.Clip>
```

Or, subscribe to the `Loading` event of your root `Grid`, and use the new `InsetClip` API from [Composition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.insetclip). This way you don't need to manually update it at all.

```
private void OnRootGridLoading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
{
    var rootVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(Root);
    var clip = rootVisual.Compositor.CreateInsetClip();
    rootVisual.Clip = clip;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a Polygon instead of clipping the rectangle?

Comment: @jsmyth886 It's much more flexible this way. You can animate it, change the corner radius, angle, etc.